# NodeJs Initialize array inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I decided to use handlebars in my nodejs project so for index page, I want to collect all information related to posts,pages,categories etc.

I have a function that returns post from database like below;

```
exports.getPosts = function(req, res){

    Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        var postsMap = {};

        if (err){
            res.status(400);
        }
        else{

            posts.forEach(function(post) {
              postsMap[post._id] = post;
            });

            res.jsonp(postsMap);
        }
    });
};
```

I want to change that function to the below prototype;

```
function getPosts(req, res){
        var posts = [
                {
                    "url": "#",
                    "title": "home!",
                    "content": "home desc"
                },
                {
                    "url":"#2",
                    "title": "about",
                    "content": "about desc)" 
                }
            ]

    return posts;                    
}
```

I have tried something like below code, but posts array is not initialized and returns undefined;

```
function getPosts(req, res){
    var posts = [];
    Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        var postsMap = {};
        if (err){
            res.status(400);
        }
        else{
            posts.forEach(function(post) {
              postsMap[post._id] = post;
            });
           posts.push(postsMap);
        }
    });
    return posts;
}
```

How can i deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final snippet of code, the function passed to `Posts.find` will not run until way after the function has returned

The order of execution will be (see comments):

```
function getPosts(req, res){
    var posts = []; //// 1
    Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        var postsMap = {}; //// 3
        if (err){
            res.status(400);
        }
        else{
            posts.forEach(function(post) {
              postsMap[post._id] = post;
            });
           posts.push(postsMap);
        }
    });
    return posts; // 2
}
```

This is because Javascript is asynchronous and will not wait for `Post.find` to complete its call to the database. Instead it will keep going and will call the `function(err, posts)` later on.

Usually to fix this, we give callbacks to your functions. Your code can be refactored to:

```
function getPosts(callback){ // Note that i removed res, req from this as it is good practice to separate out request handling from data fetching. Instead I moved it to the usage function mentioned later
    Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        var postsMap = {};
        if (err){
            callback(err);
        }
        else{
            posts.forEach(function(post) {
              postsMap[post._id] = post;
            });
            callback(null, postsMap);
        }
    });
}
```

When you use `getPosts`, you can do:

```
function otherFunction(req, res){
    getPosts(function(err, postsMap){
         // This will start running once getPosts is done

         if(err)
             res.status(400);
         else
            res.jsonp(postsMap);
    })

    // This runs almost immediately and before getPosts is done
}
```

Comment: I understand the main idea. Thanks for it. Btw, when i tried to implemente the code like you shared, i got the error which is "TypeError: callback is not a function." I put if(callback) statement to deal with that problem. Is that true approach? And also i just put that statement before "callback(null, postsMap);" Should i put it everywhere where i am calling callback as function?

Comment: @Ananbuker, that shouldn't happen, make sure that you are passing in a callback function in the right argument position where ever you use getPosts and make sure it is listed in the arguments to getPosts

Comment: how can i put the value inside callback into that string?

`code
getPosts(function(err, postsMap){
         if(err)
             res.status(400);
         else
             console.log(postsMap);
    })
    //var ppi;
    //console.log(getPosts(ppi));
    res.render("index.html",{"posts":'postsMap inside getPosts'}); code`

Comment: @Ananbuker, If I am understanding your question, you should be able to just do `res.render("index.html", {posts: postMap})` and it should pass the object that was created in getPosts in to your renderer to be used in what ever way your template is set up to work.

Comment: can you please have a look at this link [ https://jsfiddle.net/dudq02yq/ ]

Comment: Place the `res.render...` line in place of `return postsMap;`. This way it renders after `getPosts` is done (aka in the callback function).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand, you want to put the `Post.find()` function into the `results` variable, true ?

**Problem 1 :** Your callback take two arguments, the second is `posts`.

This create a variable that works only in the callback, so you can't access to the variable that is into the `getPosts()` function.

The function you've made is only returning an empty array because you can't access it.

**Problem 2 :** You're attempting to return a value synchronously but you're using an asynchronous function.

This is a sample code that should work :

```
function getPosts(req, res, callback) {
    var glob_posts = [];

    Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        var postsMap = {};

        if(err)
            res.status(400);
        else {
            posts.forEach(function(post) {
              postsMap[post._id] = post;
            });

            glob_posts.push(postsMap);
            callback(glob_posts);
        }
    });
}
```

And you can use the function by this way :

```
getPosts(req, res, function(posts) {
    // The 'posts' variable contains current posts
});
```

I hope that helped you :)